# How to iterate over solid-js children with typescript annotations

Tags: typescript, loops, for-loop, solid-js

Say I have the following component, how would I iterate over and render each child to do stuff like wrapping each child with other components?

```
interface StuffProps {
  children: `?`
}

function Stuff({ children }: StuffProps) {
  // ?
}
```

I've tried setting `children: JSX.Element` and then doing `<For each={children}> ... </For>` but it gives me a typescript error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is right, but I may have found an answer using the [`children` helper function](https://www.solidjs.com/tutorial/props_children) provided by solid-js ([api docs](https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#children)).

My solution looks something like this:

```
import { JSX, children } from 'solid-js';

interface StuffProps {
  children: JSX.Element
}

function Stuff(props: StuffProps) {
  const cs = children(() => props.children).toArray()
  <For each={cs}> ... </For>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are not going to use children in some effects, you can wrap children with some JSX element directly:

```js
import { Component, JSXElement } from 'solid-js';
import { render } from 'solid-js/web';

const Stuff: Component<{ children: JSXElement }> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div><span>Wrapper:{props.children}</span></div>
  )
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Stuff>
        <h1>Some Title</h1>
      </Stuff>

      <Stuff>
        <h1>Other Title</h1>
        <p>Some paragraph</p>
      </Stuff>
    </div>
  );
}

render(() => <App />, document.body);
```

Here we avoid destructuring props intentionally because it will remove reactivity since you will be assigning them into some local variable. Reactivity is transmitted between components through function calls. But I will ignore this rule for now for clarity.

If you are going to use `props.children` with`For` components you will get error because children is not guaranteed to be an array since JSX element can be any of  `number` | `boolean` | `Node` | `JSX.ArrayElement` | `JSX.FunctionElement` | `(string & {})` | `null` | `undefined`.

So, you need to make sure children is an array:

```js
import { render, } from 'solid-js/web';
import { Component, JSXElement } from 'solid-js';

const Stuff: Component<{ children: JSXElement }> = (props) => {
  const children = Array.isArray(props.children) ? props.children : [props.children];
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>{children.map(child => child)}</li>
    </ul>
  )
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Stuff>
        <h1>Some Title</h1>
      </Stuff>

      <Stuff>
        <h1>Other Title</h1>
        <p>Some paragraph</p>
      </Stuff>
    </div>
  );
}

render(() => <App />, document.body);
```

Now you can use it with `For` component:

```js
import { render, } from 'solid-js/web';
import { Component, For, JSXElement } from 'solid-js';

const Stuff: Component<{ children: JSXElement }> = (props) => {
  const children = Array.isArray(props.children) ? props.children : [props.children];
  return (
    <ul>
      <For each={children}>
        {item => <li>{item}</li>}
      </For>
    </ul>
  )
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Stuff>
        <h1>Some Title</h1>
      </Stuff>

      <Stuff>
        <h1>Other Title</h1>
        <p>Some paragraph</p>
      </Stuff>
    </div>
  );
}

render(() => <App />, document.body);
```

Solid provides this convenience through `children` function from the main library but you will still get type error if you use them with `For` component. That is because the result can be `false | readonly unknown[] | null | undefined` but this can be fixed by using `.toArray` method instead of function invocation:

```js
import { render, } from 'solid-js/web';
import { children, Component, For, JSXElement } from 'solid-js';

const Stuff: Component<{ children: JSXElement }> = (props) => {
  const resolved = children(() => props.children);

  return (
    <ul>
      <For each={resolved.toArray()}>
        {item => <li>{item}</li>}
      </For>
    </ul>
  )
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Stuff>
        <h1>Some Title</h1>
      </Stuff>

      <Stuff>
        <h1>Other Title</h1>
        <p>Some paragraph</p>
      </Stuff>
    </div>
  );
}

render(() => <App />, document.body);
```

As I said, this is a convenience for accessing children inside effects. Extracting them only to wrap in another element does not much make sense since you can do that directly like because expressions are valid JSX elements:

```js
<div>{props.children}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution to this question is actually to use the ParentComponent (or ParentProps if you prefer using a function) provided by solid-js.

You can read more about it by [heading over the documentation here:)](https://www.solidjs.com/guides/typescript#component-types)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).